# Can I control how many options makes a select tag become scrollable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please take a look at this two `<select>` tags:

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  
</select>
```

As you see, the first one isn't scrollable, but the second one is. So it means, if I write lots of `<option>` attributes in a `<select>` tag, it will become scrollable automatically.

I'm trying to reduce that number which causes it be scrollable. For example, I want to make a `<select>` tag only has 7 `<option>` but is displayed with a scrollbar. Is it possible? Can I configure this with JavaScript?

I have tested adding a `<div>` surrounding the `<select>` tag as a wrapper and limiting its `height`, but nothing happened.

Comment: You can not control the behavior of select on how many items it shows when you click on it unless you are talking about "multiple"

Comment: You tagged the question with `jQuery`. Does that mean you would be fine using a plugin to replace the standard `select`? If so, you'll find plenty that fits your purpose. Or you could even write one yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.holder{
  position:relative;
  height:20px;
}

select{
 
position:absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <select onfocus='this.size=5;' 
onblur='this.size=1;' 
onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>one</option>
</select>
  </div>


<h1>Random text</h1>
```

Not a straight forward way, but you can set the size `onfocus` and once selected and lost focus, set the size to 1 again.

Check  out the code I added, you just need to update `onfocus='this.size=5;'` and set the size you need.

Update:

Rory made a good point in the comments which I didnt think of earlier.

> This would affect the flow of the document as the increased height of
>   the select would force following elements to adapt to its new
>   dimensions

A work around for that would be to make the select lists' position `absolute` and add a `z-index` so it overlays elements below it. Check the updated code snippet

Comment: Neat approach, however be aware that this would affect the flow of the document as the increased height of the select would force following elements to adapt to its new dimensions

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agreed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Your point got me thinking and i added a work around, i think this kinda satisfies the purpose.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, but I prefer to use [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). When I download it, it contains lots of files and folders, do you know should I attach which of them to my project exactly? I guess I need both a `.css` file and a `.js` file.

Comment: @stack yeah, I would also recommend going with an existing library rather than this solution. Well you need to copy over all downloaded files into respective folders i.e css and js files and then call the method as show on this page https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ (scroll down to setup section)

Comment: @stack also take a look at https://select2.github.io/; I know that its one of the most used library for select boxes. not sure if it helps or satisfies your purpose, but take a look since its got better documentation and support

Answer (score 1):

use onfocus attribute on select

```
onfocus='this.size=;'
```

to adjust the height of select. example

```
onfocus='this.size=10;'
```

here 10 indicates the no of options, like if this.size=10 so scroll will be automatically added if more then 10 options are there in select.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact solution but something similar would be attribute size="5"

```
<select size="5">
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>two</option>

</select>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that suggests the OP would allow multiple values to be selected.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood.